# service.textSearch(request, callback) throws error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I have written a code which lists hard coded locations on left and shows locations on google map on right hand side. This application is written in knockout and there is search bar. In search bar if we search for keyword, it filters the list as well as google map markers. search value is bounded to list as well as to map. I am using service object to convert location to lat/long. Sometimes it gives correct result but most of the times when I filter some values, service.textSearch(request, callback) gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null". This error I caught in the console.log. otherwise it does not throw error. It just skips that location and does not show marker in map. Below is the snippet of code where service does not work for some of the places. Rest of the places are shown for which it works.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(AppViewModel.mapObj);
for (var place in loc) {
            var request = {
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7833,122.4167),
                radius: '500',
                query: loc[place]
            };


service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

Console log is here:-

[Console log having error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIGoh.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that `loc[place]` is not `null` for all the `place`s?

Comment: You log a lot there, why don't you log the status(2nd argument of `callback`). The status obviously isn't `OK`  . I would guess it's `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` because there are limits for requests(e.g. per sec)

Comment: Roy J,  loc[place] is not null. It is having text string for location.

Comment: Dr. Molle, In callback I am checking if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    createMapMarker(results[0]);
            }   So there is no chance of status having something else. I am printing status, it gives Status is [object Object] in console.log. It does not print status.

Comment: Dr. Molle, You are right. I checked for this condition `if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)`  and condition was true and it is happening because of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. But how to solve this issue. Thank you for catching this issue.  Sorry I was confused earlier.